# Checkbox.checked change when adding new dynamic row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I am working on a little project and am having some issues with a checkbox.  I am adding a number of checkboxes to an ASP table via code by adding rows and columns dynamically.  This all works fine except for when I go to check them based on loading a preexisting record.  For some reason some of the checkboxes are getting set to TRUE when the new row is added to the table.  Here is a little snippet of the code:

```
    newRow = New TableRow
    newRow.ID = "Class_R" + X.ToString.Trim
    newRow.Visible = True
    newRow.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)

    If CD.HasRows Then
        While CD.Read() And (Not all_done)
            If Y <= 3 Then
                newCol = New TableCell
                newCol.ID = newRow.ID + "Class_C" + Y.ToString.Trim
                newCol.Visible = True
                newCol.Width = Unit.Percentage(33)

                newChk = New CheckBox
                newChk.ID = "chkClass_" + CD("class_id").ToString.Trim
                newChk.Text = CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim
                newChk.Visible = True
                newChk.Checked = False
                If Not CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim.ToUpper = "OTHER" Then
                    newChk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:chkClass_clicked(this)")
                Else
                    newChk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:chkClass_Other_clicked(this)")
                End If
                If Array.IndexOf(arClass, newChk.ID) >= 0 Then
                    newChk.Checked = True
                Else
                    newChk.Checked = False
                End If
                newCol.Controls.Add(newChk)

                If CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim.ToUpper = "OTHER" Then
                    newTxt = New TextBox
                    newTxt.ID = "txtClass_" + CD("class_id").ToString.Trim
                    newTxt.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:update_class_txt_value(this)")

                    newChk.Checked = IIf(hidClass_chk.Value = "True", True, False)
                    If newChk.Checked = False Then
                        newTxt.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
                    Else
                        newTxt.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline")
                    End If
                    newTxt.Text = hidClass_txt.Value

                    newCol.Controls.Add(newTxt)
                End If
                newRow.Cells.Add(newCol)

                Y += 1
            Else
                tblClass.Rows.Add(newRow)
                X += 1
                newRow = New TableRow
                newRow.ID = "Class_R" + X.ToString.Trim
                newRow.Visible = True
                newRow.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)

                Y = 1

                newCol = New TableCell
                newCol.ID = newRow.ID + "Class_C" + Y.ToString.Trim
                newCol.Visible = True
                newCol.Width = Unit.Percentage(33)

                newChk = New CheckBox
                newChk.ID = "chkClass_" + CD("class_id").ToString.Trim
                newChk.Text = CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim
                newChk.Visible = True
                newChk.Checked = False
                If Not CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim.ToUpper = "OTHER" Then
                    newChk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:chkClass_clicked(this)")
                Else
                    newChk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:chkClass_Other_clicked(this)")
                End If
                If Array.IndexOf(arClass, newChk.ID) >= 0 Then
                    newChk.Checked = True
                Else
                    newChk.Checked = False
                End If
                newCol.Controls.Add(newChk)

                If CD("class_desc").ToString.Trim.ToUpper = "OTHER" Then
                    newTxt = New TextBox
                    newTxt.ID = "txtClass_" + CD("class_id").ToString.Trim
                    newTxt.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:update_class_txt_value(this)")

                    newChk.Checked = IIf(hidClass_chk.Value = "True", True, False)
                    If newChk.Checked = False Then
                        newTxt.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
                    Else
                        newTxt.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline")
                    End If
                    newTxt.Text = hidClass_txt.Value

                    newCol.Controls.Add(newTxt)
                End If
                newRow.Cells.Add(newCol)

                Y += 1
            End If
            *'This is the line causing the checked state to change'*
            tblClass.Rows.Add(newRow)
        End While
```

Any insight would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since an ASP.NET checkbox's default value for checked equals false `newChk.Checked = True` must be getting fired.  You'll need to check the value of `Array.IndexOf(arClass, newChk.ID) >= 0`, have you done this?

In addition since `newChk` is simply holding a reference to an object (not the object itself) `newCol.Controls.Add(newChk)` may be only adding the reference to the column (hence all off the checkboxes are the same!)

Comment: Thanks.  I did check the array and it is empty at this point and time.  The checkboxes are getting created correctly.  I can check the status of any checkbox by using FindControl("chkClass_3"), etc... and the one in question is showing TRUE.

Comment: I wanted to note one more thing. The checked state of the checkbox is FALSE until this line of code is executed..."tblClass.Rows.Add(newRow)"